# Printing CGRect in the LLDB, Swift 2.0, XCode 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

Assuming I have this code

```
if let keyboardFrameBegin = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
    ....
}
```

If I pause the execution inside of the `if` body, I get the following behaviour: no value is displayed in the variables menu

[image: variables menu]

The `LLDB` is also not very descriptive

```
(lldb)  po keyboardFrameBegin
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'keyboardFrameBegin'
keyboardFrameBegin
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

printing the value is also useless

```
(lldb) po print(keyboardFrameBegin)
error: <EXPR>:1:7: error: use of unresolved identifier 'keyboardFrameBegin'
print(keyboardFrameBegin)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

as well as passing the value as a parameter of a function

```
(lldb)  po NSValue(CGRect:keyboardFrameBegin)
error: <EXPR>:1:16: error: use of unresolved identifier'keyboardFrameBegin'
NSValue(CGRect:keyboardFrameBegin)
```

The compiler optimisation settings are default

[image: project settings]
[image: project settings]

This is annoying a lot. Is it possible to debug `CGRect` with XCode 7.1

Comment: It should work, but he debug results look like it hasn't been evaluated yet so doesn't exist, where is the breakpoint and what is the code on that line?

Comment: This is a bug of XCode 7.1 and it is fixed in XCode 7.2beta.See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215765/what-changed-in-xcode7-debugger-that-i-can-no-longer-view-variables-with-po

Comment: @Leo  Many thanx! Upgrading!